# c++ memory error ("double free or corruption") when explicitly calling destructor

Tags: c++, memory, glibc

I'm having the "*** glibc detected *** /home/ubuntu[....] : double free or corruption (fasttop) : 0x09851168 ***" problem.

Debugging I figured out the line that seems to be the source of the problem:

```
data[i]->~Class();
```

which refers to

```
 class Class {
public:
    Class();
    Class(char *name, double value);
    virtual ~Class();
    char *name;
    double value;
private:

};
```

then

```
    Class::Class() {
}

Class::Class(char* name, double value){
    this->name = new char[std::strlen(name)];
    std::strcpy(this->name, name);
    this->value = value;
}

Class::~Class() {
    delete name;
}
```

now, obviously I'm doing something wrong there. Anyone can tell me what?

Comment: For this kind of error its usually worth running under valgrind to get more information about what is causing the problem. (But I suspect the  answers posted already are correct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of only a couple circumstances under which you use: `data[i]->~Class();`. One is that you're using placement new to create an object at that location. The other is that you're re-initializing an object by destroying it, to be followed immediately by using placement new to create a new object there. Both of these are *fairly* advanced techniques, and quite frankly, rather unusual except if you're creating a collection class of your own.

My guess is that 1) you don't need that, and 2) you haven't really shown us the code that matters (which is mostly likely the stuff surrounding the explicit dtor call).

You do have one other minor problem from allocating `name` with `new[]`, and deleting it with `delete name;` -- the two should match up, so you should be using `delete [] name;`. Given that this is an array of `char`, however, that's mostly a technicality -- it almost certainly won't cause a problem in this case. If it was an array of objects that had non-trivial destructors, the typical symptom would be that some (most) of the objects didn't get properly destroyed (i.e., their destructors wouldn't get invoked). In theory it's just undefined behavior, so anything *could* happen, but the real chances of it being the source of your problem are extremely remote (especially, as I said, in the case of an array of `char`).

Of course, what you really should do is make `name` a `std::string` and skip all that nonsense completely anyway.

Comment: "The other is that you're re-initializing an object by destroying it, to be followed immediately by using placement new to create a new object there." that's the case.It's a list of objects, so I call the destructor when removing an object "Class" from the list.

Comment: @Johnsmith: In that case, it would probably be worthwhile to post that code, so we can see how it works (or doesn't work, as the case may be).

Answer (score 7):

The thing you're doing wrong is explicitly calling a destructor:

```
data[i]->~Class();
```

Unless you *absolutely* know that you should be explicitly calling it (this is unusual, and many huge programs never have a need to do that), you should probably instead be using `delete`:

```
delete data[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data[i]->~Class();
```

You should never call a destructor like that. Either `delete` it if it was allocated with `new`, or just do nothing and the destructor will be called when the object goes out of scope.